# Django test how to check if function was Not called

Tags: python, django

I want to write a test in order to check that a specific function was not called. Below is a pseudo example of my code:

Code

```
TestFunctionA():
  if a > b:
    TestFunctionB()
```

In order to check if it is called i do the following which is working

```
        with mock.patch('TestFunctionB') as mock_TestFunctionB:
           TestFunctionA()
           mock_TestFunctionB.assert_called_once_with()
```

If i want to check if the function TestFunctionB was **not** called i tried the following but is not working

```
        with mock.patch('TestFunctionB') as mock_TestFunctionB:
           TestFunctionA()
           assert not mock_TestFunctionB.assert_called_once_with()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a method [specifically for that](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_not_called).

```
mock_TestFunctionB.assert_not_called()
```